# Jenkins identity file not accessible

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, amazon-ec2, devsecops, tomcat

I am new to Jenkins and DevOps in general. I am trying to learn to deploy war files onto Tomcat 9.xx running on an amazon EC2 instance. Tomcat is accessible via the browser

I have the following Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    parameters {
         string(name: 'tomcat_dev', defaultValue: 'VALID_IP_HIDDEN', description: 'Staging Server')
    }

    triggers {
         pollSCM('* * * * *')
     }

stages{
        stage('Build'){
            steps {
                sh 'mvn clean package'
            }
            post {
                success {
                    echo 'Now Archiving...'
                    archiveArtifacts artifacts: '**/target/*.war'
                }
            }
        }

        stage ('Deployments'){
            parallel{
                stage ('Deploy to Staging'){
                    steps {
                        sh "scp -i /home/user/.ssh/tomcatdeployment.pem **/target/*.war ec2-user@${params.tomcat_dev}:/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.83/webapps"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to connect to my ec2 instance using the above identity file but when I run my Jenkins Pipeliine, I keep getting this error:

**scp -i /home/user/.ssh/tomcatdeployment.pem webapp/target/webapp.war ec2-user@IP_VALUE_HIDDEN:/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.83/webapps
Warning: Identity file /home/user/.ssh/tomcatdeployment.pem not accessible: Permission denied.
Host key verification failed.**

I have tried to add Jenkins to the root users list and enabled it to use sudo without a password following - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880070/how-to-run-a-script-as-root-in-jenkins

But I still encounter the same error. Can anyone help or provide some guidance?